# where to find the folder "/driver/net/"?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-4, ad-hoc-networks

I am trying to build **an adhoc network** using **Samsung Galaxy S4**.

Having established the network on the first handset, I am trying to connect another SGS4 to the same network.

The second SGS4 seems to discover the network and connect to it, however it generates, locally, a different network MAC address (BSSID) and hence can't actually connect to the same network, though it is connected to the same SSID (network-name).

In order to set a fixed BSSID in the second SGS4 I need to change some flags on the wireless-driver which usually is located in `/driver/net/wireless/`. Nonetheless, looking around, I can't find this folder in my rooted Samsung Galaxy S4. I've searched almost everywhere but can't find it.

If there is any other way to set a fixed BSSID, I'm of course open to that as well.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add some background: What do you need that directory for? What should be in there? What do you want to accomplish, what issue to solve? It could e.g. be you're "on the wrong track", or there's a better approach to solve your issue (see: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/192154)).

Comment: Yepp, much clearer now (fixed up the remains and added the adhoc-specific tag). Guess I don't need to point you to [How do i enforce wpa_cli to change the BSSID of a network](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62783/16575)?

Comment: Isn't the path in question a path *in the kernel source tree* rather than a path on the running device? Where did you read you need to set flags there?

Comment: @DanHulme: please check in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spandev/oBgAtUHTdTg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discussion you've been reading is about compiling a modified kernel and a custom ROM for the Galaxy S4, using a replacement wireless driver that's been changed to add support for ad-hoc Wi-Fi networks. The path `/driver/net/wireless` is a path in the *kernel source tree*, which contains the source code for the driver that needs to be changed before compiling the new kernel. It doesn't refer to any path on the device itself, or anything else you can change on the device.